# Incoming market feed to save in different cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have incoming market feed for a particular stock from 9.30 -3.30. The value will change every tick by tick .I have to capture the value in the cell everytime it changes and print in a different cell.I just started using VBA today ,so any help will be appreciated.

Declaring variables :

```
Dim X As Range
Dim Y As Range
Dim F As Integer
Set Y = Worksheets("Equity").Range("F158")
```

Selecting the cell where the values changes every second:

```
Set X = Worksheets("Equity").Range("F152").Value
```

Running the loop : Not sure if it is correct:

```
    For F = 0 To 10000 Step 1
        Y = X
    Next
    Y = Y + 1
End Sub
```

Please do correct if it is wrong.Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish by this code...Do you simply want to "sync" the value from `F158` to `F152`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event. Put the below code in sheet code section.
Once the value in Range F158 changes and is from 3.3 to 9.3 and its different from previous value then it will paste the value in Range G158

```
 Dim oldVal As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F158")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value >= 3.3 And Target.Value <= 9.3 Then
            If oldVal <> Target Then Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target
        End If
    End If

     oldVal = Range("F158").Value

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but 9.30 A.M to 3.30 P.M  is time..I tried this one and it seems ok i believe   Sub play()
    Dim xxx As Long, yyy As Long
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equity").Range("F78").Activate
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    DoEvents
    ActiveCell.Copy
    For xxx = 2 To 350 Step 1
    yyy = xxx + 1
    Worksheets("Equity").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
    .Range(Cells(xxx, 2), Cells(yyy, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    Next xxx
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equity").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(100, 0).Activate
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub